# How to fix an interrupted OS update?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, updates

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and ran an OS update using the Ubuntu Software Center, which was interrupted by a power cut. The error message, `A problem occurred when checking for updates.` is now present, and I can't open the terminal with the normal hotkey.

After that I tried:

```
sudo apt-get clean  
sudo apt-get -f install  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but the problems are still there.

Comment: can you open the terminal from the GUI and run `sudo apt update` ?

Comment: All packages are already **up to date** it seems.

Comment: Okay, next go with `sudo apt install -f` that should fix it.

Comment: Sorry, i think the problem might be slightly different. I ran the command and it seems as though everything has already been installed as well.

Comment: I pressed Enter originally. Unfortunately, the problems are still there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute the following commands 
`sudo apt-get autoclean`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`

You can also check the log files:

Use `tail -f /var/log/dpkg.log`
 In one terminal, and use the update command in another terminal, you should get the error which is not letting you update.